# FileNotFoundException: Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\outputs\bundle\release\launcher-release.aab does not exist

Tags: unity-game-engine

now i finish my game in unity 2020 and want to make google play app so i check on build app bundle
and at final it show this error :

```
Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\outputs\bundle\release\launcher-release.aab does not exist

System.IO.File.Move (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <f94168442e634613b6a5965ed17c38f4>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <f94168442e634613b6a5965ed17c38f4>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <f94168442e634613b6a5965ed17c38f4>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <f94168442e634613b6a5965ed17c38f4>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <208f92fc783546f9abbe643bfc23920c>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

also i check on custom base gradle template in player settings and i use unity 2020.3.21f1 / gradle version 6.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Open `Assets\Plugins\Android\baseProjectTemplate.gradle` (if this file does not exist, open Project Setting > Publishing Setting > Check Custom Base Gradle Template)

Find the line `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:` and set its version to:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'`

And try using gradle 6.8 or the version that came with your Unity installation

Comment: thanks for your time , i tried you sol with gradle version 6.1.1 + 6.5 and they didn't work 
i will try version 6.8 and 6.9 and tell you thanks again for help

Comment: can i ask you what is classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1' version mean ?
i mean when i set version to 3.4.3 it work but without google play check and when i set it to 4.0.1 it show error when i build apk or aap

Comment: i try your sol but same error

Comment: what error do you get when you use 3.4.3? can you post the content of your baseProjectTemplate.gradle file?

Comment: i fix this error finally by use 3.4.3 and active launcherTemplate from player settings and add this code in final line and it work perfect

Comment: tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
if (task.name.startsWith("bundle")) {
def renameTaskName = "rename${task.name.capitalize()}Aab"
def flavor = task.name.substring("bundle".length()).uncapitalize()
tasks.create(renameTaskName, Copy) {
def path = "${buildDir}/outputs/bundle/${flavor}/"
from(path)
include "launcher.aab"
destinationDir file("${buildDir}/outputs/bundle/${flavor}/")
rename "launcher.aab", "launcher-release.aab"
}

task.finalizedBy(renameTaskName)
}
}

Comment: thanks for your time

Comment: @merna I'm having this same problem I change classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0' to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0' in baseprojecttemplate and can u please tell me what did u add in launchertemplate from player settings? I'm using unity 2020.1.17f